# Find a point with given vector and fixed height

Tags: math, vector

[image]

Point A as player's eyes.

Point B as the edge of obstacle.

Point C as the limited range that player can see (C.y = B.y + 2)

How I can find point C with the given information?

Comment: This looks like a simple case of just using similar triangles to solve for a missing value. Alternatively, you can use trigonometry (in this case, the cosine ratio) if you know the angle of A. Have you tried looking up the formulas for either of those approaches (or any at all)?

Comment: @Serlite i'm not very good at math (actually i forgot all of them) and yes i can calculate angle of A..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to this, if you know angle A then B is identical. If you know the height of the BC triangle, then you can solve the distance to C with some trig.

[image]

I'm not a math genius myself but here are the relationships for right triangles.

Now if we call the bottom right vertex of the BC triangle "D", we can do this math. We're going to be looking for the adjacent side's length:

Tan(B) = CD/DB  | *Start with this. Since we know the opposite and we want to find the adjacent, we use the tangent.*

DB * Tan(B) = CD | *Now multiply both sides by DB to move it over to the left side.*

DB = CD/Tan(B) | *And then divide both sides by Tan(B) to get the unknown DB by itself.*

So now that we know that, you can just plug in the numbers. Lets say angle B=45 degrees and the fixed height is 2.

DB = 2/tan(45)

DB = 2/1

DB = 2

(Please excuse the awful snip job)
[image]

So these functions exist in the Mathf class, and just refer to the diagram when trying to figure it out.

Also it's pretty late, if anyone's noticed a mistake please feel free to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

The line that connects A and B is y=m*x+n

slope: m = (By-Ay)/(Bx-Ax)

intercept: n = Ay-m*Ax

You already have Cy = By+H

So to find Cx we plug all of the above into the line equation:

Cy = m*Cx + n

Cx = (By + H - n)/m

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that A point is coordinate origin:

```
 C.Y = B.Y + H
 C.Y / B.Y = C.X / B.X   // triangles similarity
 C.X = B.X * (B.Y + H) / B.Y = B.X * (1 + H/B.Y)
```